# change dictionary values to dictionaries from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, dictionary

I have a list with 12 dictionaries, and the main dictionary with 12 keys. For every key in the main dictionary, I want to change the value to dictionary from the list of the dictionaries that I have. I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
values = []

for lst in href_lst:
    val = dict(Counter(lst))
    values.append(val)

for key in traffic_dict:
    for dict in values:
        traffic_dict[key] = dict
```

The output is that every key in the main dictionary has the same value. I need for every key a different value (different dictionary from the list).

Comment: Please add a little sample to the question.

Comment: I give -1 because you're overriding a builtin Python type. *you should never do this!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
values = [dict(Counter(lst)) for lst in href_lst]
for key, value in zip(traffic_dict, values):
    traffic_dict[key] = value
```

Or, if you don't need `values` later, just `zip`:

```
for key, lst in zip(traffic_dict, href_lst):
    traffic_dict[key] = dict(Counter(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your second loop here

```
for key in traffic_dict:
    for dict in values:
        traffic_dict[key] = dict
```

is running even after assigning the value.
This will assign the last value in the list "values" to every "key".

Corrected code sample,

```
i = 0
for key in traffic_dict:
    traffic_dict[key] = values[i]
    i += 1
```

There can be multiple ways to do this. The above code is one of the ways.